# Double images in Outlook on email

Tags: html, css, email

I am doing a responsive email where I can move the images if the email is being viewed on mobile.Everything looks great except in Outlook. It is displaying it in both places. I read that outlook does not recognize the "display:none" code. Is there anything else that can be done?

Here is what I have my code looking like and its working on everything but outlook.

Media Query Code

```
     @media only screen and (max-device-width: 479px) {
                #mobile {display:block}
                #desktop {display:none;mso-hide: all;}


        }

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 480px) {
                #mobile {display:none;mso-hide: all;}
                #desktop {display:block}

}
        }
```

And here is the html I am using.

```
  <table id="mobile" align="right" width="35%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="deviceWidth">
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="top" align="right" class="hisrc">
                                    <p style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0; margin:0; font-family:Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:11px; color:323338; text-align:left; line-height:15px;">
                                    <img src="vna-logo.png" alt="" border="0" style="padding-bottom:18px;border-radius: 4px; width: 220px;" class="deviceWidth" />  


                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>

 <table id="desktop" align="right" width="35%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="deviceWidth">
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="top" align="right" class="hisrc">
                                    <p style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0; margin:0; font-family:Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:11px; color:323338; text-align:left; line-height:15px;">
                                    <img src="vna-logo-2.png" alt="" border="0" style="padding-bottom:18px;border-radius: 4px; width: 220px;" class="deviceWidth" />  


                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table id="mobile" align="right" width="35%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="deviceWidth" style="display:none;">
```

Should hide mobile version by default, will stay hidden on clients where queries are not accepted